# How can I ascertain the amount of energy (j) lost to air resistance given that I have already calculated the drag force in newtons?

Tags: kinematics

So, I have conducted an "experiment" in which a basketball has been dropped from a height 1.83m and I intend on analysing its motion during this period.

I have found that the force due to air resistance is 0.047N, and I would like to know how to ascertain the amount of energy lost through air resistance given this value. My best idea thus far has been to use "Work done = Force * Distance", which gives me a value in joules, but I'm not entirely sure if this describes the energy lost due to air resistance.

This is my first question on this website and I'm sorry if this question is vague, if you want any other background information I'm more than happy to try and comply :,)

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE :) Are you familiar with integral calculus? Have you tried to go from E = F*s with integral calculus E = \int F ds

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't been introduced to calculus yet, how would I go about applying it?

Comment: "I have found that the force due to air resistance is 473.74N"

There are several worries here. (1) The faster the ball is moving, the greater the force of air resistance on it. So your figure must be some sort of mean value. (2) I'd very much doubt that your 5 significant figures are justified. (3) especially since the pull of gravity on a basketball of mass 0.625 kg is only about 6 N, so it's hard to see how the ball can have fallen at all!

I'm sorry this all seems so negative, but you need to tell us how you set about finding the air resistance, or where your figure has come from.

Comment: I have used a mean velocity value over the 1.83m the ball travelled in order to simplify things, is there a simple, better way to do this? I see what you mean about the gravitational force though, it looks like I screwed up the units I used for reference area when calculating the air resistance. I can't seem to see where I've gone wrong mathematically.

Comment: Oh I'm so silly, I was using a reference area value in cm instad of m. The drag force in newtons is in fact 4.7*10^-2. I don't have anything to reference though, so I'm unsure as to whether that's too small a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Force x Distance is the right idea, but your air resistance increases as the ball gets faster. If you're assuming that air resistance is proportional to speed, and that it's small compared with pull of gravity, then my back-of-envelope calculation (using a little calculus) showed that

Work done against air resistance
 = $\frac{4}{3}$ air resistance at mean speed $\times$ height fallen.

However, this way of setting about things doesn't seem like an experiment at all to me. For air resistance effects to show up in an experiment, you need to drop the ball from a much greater height. If you have some means of measuring the ball's speed just before it hits the ground, it's very easy to find the work done against air resistance, using the KE calculated from the measured speed. I'll leave the details to you.

Comment: Thanks for that equation, it'll work perfectly! Just for the record, the experiment barely involves air resistance, it's more so about the impact different surfaces have on an object's capacity for rebound. That's why I'm not too* concerned with the accuracy of the drag calculation, as long as it's ballpark.